# Blank Github page on personal portfolio website

Tags: html, reactjs, github, github-pages

dev newbie here.
So I've recently created my personal portfolio, github repository -> https://github.com/LuisssM/Portfolio
and, when lauching the https://luisssm.github.io/Portfolio/ website, it gives the read-me file content, and with the https://github.com/LuisssM/Portfolio/public, it gives the index.html, but blank. Could someone help me in whats causing this and what should I change in the code for it to load the index.js that works 100% in my local host server?

I've tried changing its path, tried a solution I saw here on stack overflow of changing private to false in package.json, tried to add the "homepage": "https://[YourGitHubAccountName].github.io/[YourProjectName]" in package.json as well,  but neither of this stuff worked out.

Comment: Please nuke whatever you currently have and follow along with this doc carefully https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages

Comment: Not directly related to your question but your page is redirecting to https://greensock.com/requires-membership/?plugin=DrawSVGPlugin&source=trial for me.

Comment: @MadsHougesen Yes, seems like I'm using an svg plugin that requires premium membership, I used it for an svg logo.. thinking about dropping the svg lol

Comment: @MadsHougesen not being able to deal with greensock membership error, do you have any idea on this fix? I've removed everything svg related but maybe there is something on the code im not seeing

Comment: Removing the [`gsap-trial`](https://github.com/LuisssM/Portfolio/blob/4bb72570236061f091f7d671b4972cfe04d97db7/package.json#L15) dependency should fix it. According to the package it is "only intended for experimentation during development" ([source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gsap-trial)).

Comment: @MadsHougesen dependency removed on json file, still giving the error :/

Comment: And you redeployed to github pages? 
Because then I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: I've pushed all changes to github, yes. If u check my json files and ctrl + f for GSAP, there is nothing there calling it..

Comment: Good news, the luisssm.github.io/Portfolio/ isnt showing the svg error message anymore, but now its showing an empty blue page lol..

Comment: Any idea of why is it behaving like this? Host server doesnt show any errors

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use gh-pages (npm install gh-pages ), which will create an additional branch for you in which your build will be deployed. in this thread there will only be a build and there will be an index in the root folder.

[https://blog.logrocket.com/deploying-react-apps-github-pages/#:~:text=Adding%20the%20GitHub%20Pages%20dependency%20package](https://blog.logrocket.com/deploying-react-apps-github-pages/#:%7E:text=Adding%20the%20GitHub%20Pages%20dependency%20package)

Comment: Hello Alexander, if you check the link now, the webpage almost loads, but it is giving me an svg error, do you have any idea about that? I've deleted everything that is svg from my side as you can see in the folders